# I'd like to know what happens when a function create objects in it

Tags: c++

I know that the object created in a function is deleted when the function reaches the end of it.
(When 'new' is not used)

1.

```
void test() {
list<int> temp(5,5);
list<int>* temp2 = new list<int>(5,4);
}

int main() {
test();
return 0;
}
```

I could see the destructor is called only once for the object 'temp'. 
Then is the memory allocated for 'temp2' never deleted? even though the program is over?

2.

```
char* foo() {
    return "HELLO"
}

char* foo2() {
    char* temp = "HI"
    return temp
}

int main() {
    cout << foo() << endl;
    cout << foo2() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I could see it prints two strings, "HELLO" and "HI". but.. why?
Is it a same situation when an object is made with 'new'?

Comment: 1. A typical operating system would deallocate all memory allocated for a process, when the process terminates. That's not an excuse to write memory leaks into your code.

Comment: 2. `Is it a same situation when an object is made with 'new'?` No. What makes you believe so? There are no instances of the keyword `new` in this code.

Comment: String literals are allocated in a static memory region and exist for the duration of the program. That's why there's no problem with your second example.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @IgorTandetnik . I don't know then why I got the right result by cout << foo() << endl; . The string created in the function foo() must be removed... no?~

Comment: Ahha! I got it... @0x499602D2, Thanks !
Even though it works, I guess it is very bad and dangerous coding styles. Am I right?

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong about returning a pointer to a string literal. It's better to make that pointer a `const char*` though (an attempt to modify a string literal exhibits undefined behavior).

Comment: But most importantly, you shouldn't even bother with raw C-strings. Just use the standard string class [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allocate an object with `new`, its destructor runs only when you destroy it with `delete`.  If you never call `delete` on the object, that's a memory leak.  (Most modern operating systems will free all your program's memory when the program terminates, but destructors won't run for leaked objects since they're being freed after the program has already ended.)

String literals like your `"HELLO"` and `"HI"` are not allocated dynamically, so they don't have to be freed.  Your `foo` and `foo2` functions return pointers to predefined data that was loaded into memory along with your program's code.  (And string literals are stored in an area of memory that's marked read-only, so you should use `char const *` to avoid accidentally trying to modify their contents.)

Answer (score 0):

SeongYun Ko, I believe your doubt is: If the value of the temp variable is deleted, how then does it appear printed out?

You have to understand that when you call the function foo or foo2, the variables you declared in those functions are created and destroyed... every time you call them. So if you call the foo function twice, you will print out two "HELLO" statements, and the logical process will be something like this:

call foo function first time: temp variable created, tem variable returned, temp variable destroyed, print foo returned variable

call foo function second time: temp variable created, tem variable returned, temp variable destroyed, print foo returned variable

So basically every time you call a function, the variables inside will be created and destroyed, every time.